# Differential Equation Application to the Real World

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I came across two cases of the roots of characteristics equations, where the roots were on the right hand plane of the imaginary axis. Could these cases happen in the real world?

Comment: Please add more context; in particular, giving us the specific equation would help

Comment: Sorry I do not have a equation. I could only remember that the cases were both unstable and unreal.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, instability really does occur in the real world.  Of course, real-world variables don't usually grow indefinitely: what generally happens is that nonlinear effects become important (e.g. something breaks).

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: The classical example: an [inverted pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_pendulum).